# Vlookup to check all values before returning value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

i have this Project, I have to check values from a different sheet and copy the value of the Cell beside it.

Sheet 1

```
Billy
Paul
Mike
Jesse
```

Sheet 2

```
Billy |
Paul | X
Jesse | 
Billy | X
Mike | X
```

I am working on Sheet 1 while getting values from Sheet 2.

I just need to return the value in Col 2, I have it working with =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B148,LateReports!B:C,2,0),"-")

But with Billy not having an X the first time it stops the look up and returns blank. How do i check the whole list, compare cell values and if it equals "X" once return it?

Comment: Generally VLOOKUP documentation will tell you  the leftmost column of the table should be sorted alphabetically, in this case that would put the two Billy entries on successive rows,  That alone doesn't completely solve this problem tho.  There is no recursive flag or anything like it for vlookup.

Comment: Do you know another function i can use?
I'm used to the basic programing functions like If, Or, etc. i was hoping i could just place it in there

Comment: @Tyson, wrong. Vlookup only requires sorted data for an approximate lookup with TRUE or 1 as the fourth argument. For an exact lookup sorting won't make a difference. That is not the problem here.

Comment: What is the value in column 2 -- a number, text or actually the letter "x"? Please describe your data in more detail. Edit your question. Don't put detail into comments.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort your lookup table by Col A and then descending Col B. In that case VLOOKUP will find the "Billy" with the X first.

Comment: I should have added more info about the sheets. Sheet 2 has another Col for Date, which is what it is sorted by.

Comment: Does the file have to be an XLSX file, or can it include a User Defined Function (XLSM)?

Comment: It does have to be a XLSX,

Comment: You could create a third sheet sorted as I suggested and hide it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

How about (assuming your Sheet2 columns are in columns A and B, and that your Sheet1 column is in column A), type this in Column B of Sheet1:

`=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A1,Sheet2!B:B,"X")>0,"I found it!","I didn't find it")`

This works if you know you want to look specifically for "X", and then counts how many times it finds the two tests of (a) it's Bill (because his name is in A1; when you copy the formula down it'll do A2, A3, etc, which will be Paul and Mike and so on), and (b) there's an X.

If, however, you don't know it's called 'X', and want to find out what it *is* called, then you have a problem because how does Excel know which line to give you?  The blank line?  A line with "X", or a line with "Y", etc?

If it's not "x"s you're looking for, but any non-blank line, then do the same as above but

`=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A1,Sheet2!B:B,"<>""")>0,"I found it!","I didn't find it")`

which looks for anything which doesn't equal nothing ("" being nothing, <>"" being not equal to nothing, "<>""" being not equal to nothing in quotes to make it work.

I think those work anyway, but they only tell you whether something's there, not what it is :-)

---

An alternative approach is to make a pivot table (Insert -> PivotTable) and filter out blanks using the filter, and put the Name and X columns into the Row Labels, perhaps.  Then you can do a VLOOKUP on the columns of the pivot table, although that still won't help if you have multiple non-blank entries for each person as it still won't know which to look up.

Though you might find the pivot table actually gives you the answer you want anyway without any more formulae needed, depending on what you need it for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Index(Match) to "keep searching". It will return a value like VLOOKUP would.

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$C$5,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5=Sheet1!A1)*(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5="X"),0),3)}
```

Declare the array area for INDEX, Sheet2!$A$1:$C$5, including a date column.

Call MATCH inside of INDEX, using "1" as your lookup value, and "1" is "TRUE"

(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5=Sheet1!A1) will equal 1, and so will (Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5="X"), which will return 1 when we multiply them returning a "TRUE" value.

We close our MATCH with a "0", which will states we want an exact match between "1" and our second argument which we multiplied.

Close the INDEX with the column of the array you'd like to reference, in this case "3" for column C which should contain a date as you stated in a comment.

MOST IMPORTANT, instead of just hitting ENTER, use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER which will place those curly brackets around your formula {formula}

Here's what the excel sheets should look like.

```
Sheet1- Two columns
Billy|INDEX(MATCH)
Paul|drag your INDEX(MATCH)
Mike|drag your INDEX(MATCH)
Jesse|drag your INDEX(MATCH)

Sheet2- Three Columns including Date in "C"
Billy||42450
Paul|X|42450
Jesse| |42451
Billy|X|42452
Mike|X|42452
```